# How do I melt the Frozen Riddler Trophies?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've come across a Frozen Riddler Trophy in a place under Wonder Tower. The gadgets I've acquired so far did not work to melt it. How can I melt the ice on Frozen Riddler Trophies?

The frozen riddler trophy is hanged and it's on a very high point. I just can get close by standing on a plank at a parallel position. If I go there again, I'll provide a screenshot.

Comment: if you supply a screenshot of the trophy in question it would help me give a more specific answer

Comment: If a trophy is "frozen," it just keeps you from batclaw-ing it.  You have to find a way to pick it up without the 'claw.

Comment: I progressed in the game and didn't take a screenshot when I was there. If I go there again, I'll provide a screenshot. FYI, the frozen riddler trophy is hanged and on a very high point. I just can get close by standing on a plank at a parallel position.

Comment: Is it hanging by a rope? Use your batarang to cut the rope by aiming it in the middle of the rope.

Comment: Yes, it is hanging by a rope. OK, I'll try that as soon as I go there.

Comment: I think I know which one you're referring to now.  If that one falls into the water you'll need the frozen grenade to make a platform for you to go and fetch it.

Comment: See the second part of my answer, I mention that when the trophy is hanging by rope, you need, as others have pointed out, to cut the rope first

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Frozen trophies can be picked just by standing next to them and picking them up (rather than by the BatClaw from afar). If a frozen trophy is floating on the water, you'll need to throw a freeze grenade next to it and stand on the platform to pick it up. There's at least one instance where the trophy hangs above the water, in that case, you'll need to drop it into the water by cutting the rope it hangs from with the Batarang.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to pick them up just like any other trophy, frozen or not.

Comment: Batclaw doesn't work. It is hanged and I have to remotely melt/grab it.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar - Nope, you don't have to (and in fact CAN'T) melt it.  You just can't Batclaw it, so you have to get right next to it to grab it.  See the top-voted answer.